# Parameterless View Constructor In Prism 6

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Here's what I'm trying to do (and there may be a better way): 
    My application is meant to keep track of players in a game. As players join the game events will be sent (using the event aggregator) to create a user control and add it to a List which is connected to an ItemControl. When they leave the game, events will be sent to remove the user control from the list.

The actual ItemContol looks like this - the Players binding is to the List so that it can show the individual player user controls:

```
<UserControl>
        <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Players}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:PlayerListView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is inserted into a grid row/column of the main window view just by using the below command:

```
<views:PlayerListView />
```

The issue I am running into is this last line `<views:PlayerListView />` as it is saying that "There are no accessible PlayerListView constructors". Here is the code behind with the constructor and I believe the reason I am getting this error is because the constructor isn't parameterless -- here is the code-behind.

```
public partial class PlayerListView : UserControl
{
    public PlayerListView(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PlayerListViewModel(eventAggregator);
    }
}
```

I need the PlayerListViewModel to have the IEventAggregator in its constructor but am not sure the appropriate way to do it. I've viewed this Stack Overflow post: [Prism MVVM - How to pass an IEventAggregator to my ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090633/prism-mvvm-how-to-pass-an-ieventaggregator-to-my-viewmodel) but am not sure if that is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do or not and am slightly confused on how I would incorporate it.

Adding PlayerListViewModel

```
namespace PlayerTools.ViewModels
{
    class PlayerListViewModel
    {
        #region Private Fields
        IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        #endregion

        #region Public Commands
        ICommand AddPlayerToListCommand { get; set; }
        ICommand RemovePlayerFromListCommand { get; set; }
        #endregion

        public List<PlayerStackPanelViewModel> Players = new List<PlayerStackPanelViewModel>();

        #region Constructor
        public PlayerListViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            Players.Add(new PlayerStackPanelViewModel()
            {
                PlayerName = "Steven",
                PlayerClass = "Tennis",
                CurrentLevel = 10,
                NumberOfDeaths = 0
            });
            Players.Add( new PlayerStackPanelViewModel()
            {
                PlayerName = "Steven",
                PlayerClass = "Soccer",
                CurrentLevel = 17,
                NumberOfDeaths = 1
            });

            //Commands
            AddPlayerToListCommand = new DelegateCommand<PlayerStackPanelViewModel>(AddPlayerToList);
            RemovePlayerFromListCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(RemovePlayerFromList);
        }
        #endregion

        public void AddPlayerToList(PlayerStackPanelViewModel player)
        {
            Players.Add(player);
        }

        public void RemovePlayerFromList(string playerName)
        {
            Players.Remove(Players.Single(s => s.PlayerName == playerName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add code of your viewmodel? List of Players?,

Comment: @fhnaseer Added now to end of description. I haven't subscribed to/published any events as i can't get code to successfully build currently. If you need any other classes/code or explanations, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ViewModelLocator](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/viewmodel-locator.html) to wire the `DataContext` of a view to an instance of your view model:

**PlayerListView.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class PlayerListView : UserControl
{
    public PlayerListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**PlayerListView.xaml:**

```
<UserControl ... prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" />
```

Your use of the event aggregator should be implemented in the view model and not in the view.

Comment: thanks. That will get it to compile but apparently I have other issues as the user controls are not showing in the ItemsControl.